# Grub unaccessible after windows 10 and ubuntu 14 install

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I would like to be able to dual boot on windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.

First, I tried to install windows 10 after Ubuntu 14. I was not able to dual boot after that. I know that this is not the best way in this order.
Here is what I tried to repair grub:

> https:// help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
>
> https:// sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/6

Anything worked. I send the URL of the result of bootRepair to boot.repair@gmail.com but their service has stopped.

Then, I have removed both OS and reinstalled windows, first, and then Ubuntu to get the dual boot. During Ubuntu installation I checked that I wanted grub as boot loader to be able to choose which partition I wanted to use each time my PC starts. But it didn't work either.

Does anyone had the same issue? Any workaround?

### EDIT

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10797259/) is the bootRepair report for more details

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1028794648 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,gpt6)/boot/grub on this drive.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.00-3.35) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Repair log. This should provide sufficient information to investigate your issue.

Answer (score -1):

in your second case scenario where you install win-10 first you needed to have grub installed to /dev/sda when you install Ubuntu,,,,,assuming /dev/sda is the drive it all went to.
 if you chose say /dev/sda2 grub got installed to a partition table (which you can do if you are going to chain load from one grub install to the next)instead of the MBR (master boot record)of the primary drive ,,,which is where you want it .